# SQL row output grouped by time stamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got the following table structure:

```
Time_Stamp  Number
9/07/13     234
9/07/13     345
9/07/13     456
10/07/13    765
10/07/13    834
10/07/13    257
```

And I would like to print it like this:

```
9/07/13     234 345 456
10/07/13    765 834 257
```

Any idea how i could go about it?

EDIT:

This is how I'm printing the rows at the moment:

```
    if(!$result_db_post = $db->query($query)){
          die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
      }

       while($row = $result_db_post->fetch_assoc()){

          echo $row['time_stamp'] ." ". $row['number'];
          echo "<br />";                               
}
```

Which results in this output:

```
    9/07/13 234
    9/07/13 345
    9/07/13 456
   10/07/13 765
   10/07/13 834
   10/07/13 257
```

I've tried both queries and both result in the same output.

```
select Time_Stamp, group_concat(Number separator ' ') as Numbers
from t
group by Time_Stamp;
```

And I also tried:

```
SELECT Time_Stamp, GROUP_CONCAT(Number) From table group by Time_Stamp
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the application level if there is one (e.g. a simple php loop)

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want to put the numbers in the same order as they are in the original data.  However, SQL tables are inherently unordered, so there is an issue.

It is unclear whether you want them in one column or three.  As one column, you can do it using:

```
select Time_Stamp, group_concat(Number separator ' ') as Numbers
from t
group by Time_Stamp;
```

If you want them in three columns, you can do the following:

```
select Time_Stamp,
       substring_index(group_concat(Number), ',', 1) as Number1,
       substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(Number), ',', 2), -1) as Number2,
       substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(Number), ',', 3), -1) as Number3
from t
group by Time_Stamp;
```

However, the ordering is indeterminate.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the great queries Gordon. I've edited my original post - do you know what I'm doing wrong when echoing the rows?

Comment: The ordering is defined, it's just not specified by the SQL standard. If it were indeterminate, running a `select` statement twice would give different results.

Answer (score 2):

use [GROUP_CONCAT Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), Try this query:

```
SELECT Time_Stamp, GROUP_CONCAT(Number) From table group by Time_Stamp
```

Comment: Thanks for that Akam - do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong when echoing the rows? - I've edited the post.